Is there a Jenkins replacement for greenballs? How to display build results on UI page
We just upversioned  old Jenkins version from  2.319  to  2.426
In the  old version we used plugin  https://plugins.jenkins.io/greenballs/
The  build result page would display  GreenBall on success.  Red on Fail,  Grey on abort.
Looking  very much like this:

After the Jenkins upgrade there is no icons on the build result page to identify the build result.
I have no way of knowing the build result without scanning the console.
For the record, this build was aborted but you wouldn't know it from looking at the page:

In the old versions on Build Time Trend I see all the build result status icons:

Knowing the build result at a glance in the time trend is a very usefull tool. But the new version does not have this luxury:

The Jenkins plugin page says it is obsolete and:
" The Green Balls plugin is not compatible with the new icons."
I tried disabling and  uninstalling the greenballs, in hopes that some new icon default would take over,  turns out that was wishful thinking.
What are the new icons?
What is the  successor to the Green (or Blue)  balls?
Is there a way to display the build status at a glance in the new UI?

When Jenkins migrated to SVG from GIF and PNG, that effectively broke the greenballs plugin, which has since been deprecated. Glad you found the solution.

It seems there is something wrong with your Jenkins since you are supposed to see a check mark indicating the status of your build:

Same applies for trend:

This is in-built into Jenkins and doesn't require a separate plugin, meaning that there might have been some issue during the upgrade.

SOLVED:
Turns out I was looking in the wrong place.
A colleage pointed out that perhaps for some reason the browser has svg support disabled.
Solution:  I uplifted my chrome browser to version,  126.0.6478.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)   and it works.
Now, I can see the correct Checkmarks  as listed in the response below.
Thanks for all your support.
